# Team Foundation Server 2012 on what Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, team-foundation-server, essentials-2012

I am trying to find out the optimal version of OS that I need for my Team Foundation Server 2012

As I can find it seems that TFS will run on Server 2012 but it is not specified which versions. Should there be any problems running it on an Essentials or Foundation edition?

Note: I am planning to run TFS is a virtualized environment with a Server 2012 R2 Datacenter as host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not specified because it does not matter which Windows Server 2012 edition you use. However you need to take the footnote into consideration!

64-bit versions of Windows Server 2012 ² (**Server 2012 unequal Server 2012 R2!**)

² Because Team Foundation Server installs SharePoint Foundation 2010 with the standard configuration, you can’t use it on Windows Server 2012. If you want to install Team Foundation Server on Windows Server 2012, use the advanced configuration and skip the installation of SharePoint Foundation 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592.aspx